# GET http://localhost:8005/context.blade.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to replace ajax.blade.php text with the context.blade.php text after clicking on a button. When I press the button the error occurred.

```
**app.js file:**

    function replaceText(){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let target = document.getElementById("text");
    xhr.open('GET' , 'context.blade.php' , true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                target.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.readyState === 200) {
                target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
      xhr.send();
    }
    let button = document.getElementById('ajax-button');
    button.addEventListener("click",replaceText);
```

ajax.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layout.app')
<h1 id="text">Hello Original Text </h1>
<button type="button" id="ajax-button">Change</button>
```

context.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layout.app')
<h1>Ajax change text</h1>
```

AjaxController:

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function ajax(){
        return view ('ajax');
    }
    public function ajaxContent(){
    return view('context');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/ajax','AjaxController@ajax');
Route::get('/ajaxContent','AjaxController@ajaxContent');
```

Comment: Your route is `ajax` but the url you are requesting is `context.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you be sending the request to the endpoint `'context.blade.php'`

Based on your **Route** file shouldn't it be something like:

```
xhr.open('GET' , 'ajaxContent' , true);
```

instead of:

```
xhr.open('GET' , 'context.blade.php' , true);
```

Also this:

```
let button = document.getElementById('ajax-button');
button.addEventListener("click",replaceText);
```

Has to be inside this:

```
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.readyState === 200) {
        target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        let button = document.getElementById('ajax-button');
        button.addEventListener("click",replaceText);
    }
```

Because the request is **Assynchronous** and assigning it right after the execution won't work.

```
xhr.open(method , url , async);
```

Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) documentation

If you need to load the context you could create another endpoint:

```
Route::get('/ajaxContent','AjaxController@ajaxContent');
```

In the controller:

```
AjaxController extends Controller {
    public function ajaxContent() {
        return view('context');
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is an **oversimplified** example, you could pass parameters in your GET request and validate them in the served based on parameters you sent.

Comment: I want to replace ajax.blade.php text with the context.blade.php text after clicking on a button. When I set request like xhr.open('GET', 'ajax', true); its only show "Loading..." and but not replace the text. Thatswhy I am using context.blade.php

Comment: Edited my answer. You could use "ajaxContent" as a route and load the content view.

Comment: Can you give me some details of whats happening?

Comment: I had a typo, I have changed it, i had return view(“content”) and its view(“context”)

Comment: I have update my post in route and controller. check it, please.

Comment: You still need this “xhr.open(“GET”, “ajaxContent”, true);” you still have second argument with “context.blade.php”. And you need that “click” event listener inside the if aswell

Comment: I had not update my app.js but I do like this xhr.open(“GET”, “ajaxContent”, true); still loading not replace

Comment: Still it wont work if you don’t place addEventListener inside the success condition